# Check entire string matches the RegEx or not

Tags: c#, regex

I do have the following code

```
Regex rx = new Regex(@"(\w{2}(\,\w{2})*)+");
```

I don't know how to check if the entire input string falls into that format or not
for example

```
INPUT: W2 -> true
INPUT x3,4e -> true
INPUT x3,4e,33 -> true

INPUT: x -> false
INPUT x3,e -> false
```

I do not need to find any matches! I just need to know if the input is in the correct format or not.

Thanks

Comment: Try http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3y21t6y4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Anchor it with '^' and '$'.

Comment: @Steve Howard: I did already, didnt work

Comment: In what way did it not work?  Did you try @juharr's suggestion of anchoring the pattern with ^ and $?

Answer (score 1):

@Steve Howard & @Juharr

Thank you guys, worked !

```
Regex rx = new Regex(@"^(\w{2}(\,\w{2})*)+$");
            string input = txtTermCodes.Text.Trim();
            if(rx.IsMatch(input))
                return true;
            else 
                return false;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to extract the result of the match, which is a string, then compare its length to the length of your input, like so:

```
Regex rx = new Regex(@"(\w{2}(\,\w{2})*)+");
String input = "Your input";
Match m = rx.Match(input);

if (!m.Success) return false;

return m.Length == input.Length;
```

Comment: It does not work, Try dd,dd